# Undefined function apache_request_headers() why?

Tags: php, apache

I'm trying to get header information, but when I use `apache_request_headers()` function I get a error message, but I don't know why.
Can someone help me?

> **Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function apache_request_headers()**

Link to my `phpinfo`: https://www.destakpremium.com.br/teste_header/info.php

Comment: Are you on Windows? What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: PHP version: 7.0.27
Link to phpinfo: https://www.destakpremium.com.br/teste_header/info.php